# data validation list based on checkbox value

Tags: excel

right now i have a table with information like company name and stuff.

after each line in the table there is a checkbox.

i also have data validation list that references to that table.

is there any way that only the lines in the data validation show if in the table the checkbox behind a line is ticked?

so for example i have this

```
**name checkbox**
test checked
klas unchecked
klek checked
```

and then in the list in only shows test and klek and not the klas option since that is unchecked.

Comment: If you use a `Form Control Checkbox` and if those are linked with cells of table column then it is possible.

Comment: i have those but how can i go further then.

Comment: It is very hard to post answer. Can you share a sample workbook via google drive then share download link here. Please also clarify more on that sample workbook.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g8dw_6jdnHwyjIdVTrPwVLXAL8_Ai0Nj/view?usp=sharing

here is the link.
in the tab factuur in cell A9 there is a validation list with all the names that are in the tab gegevens but on the tab gegevens there is a column called checkbox i need a checkbox in every row and when a checkbox is clicked it shows up in cell A9 in  factuur if the cell is not clicked it doesht show up

Comment: and @harun24hr hope you can help

Comment: Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the file and check it.

[Sample File Download Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eddLLIdX3FKG8g1KpvHF4uUyueXUADEU/view?usp=sharing)

I thought it would be easier but not. I am sure it will take hours to understand what is happening with formulas.

Comment: @Klaas Glad to know

Comment: did you by any change impelement any code or something because i try to putt it in another project now created checkbox and copied the formula but it only works for the top cell.

Comment: if i only copy the checkbox and the formula it doesnt work

Comment: No coding but the formula in `Helper Column` is an array formula. So need to enter it as press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` after entering the formula in cell.

Comment: Another thing is every `Checkbox` is link to each cell of `Column I` like `Checkbox1` is link to `I2` cell, Checkbox2` is link to `I3` cell. So, you have to do it as well in your project.